# Android APK - differences in Linux vs. Windows

Tags: android, windows, ubuntu, gradle, apk

I am using 2 build environments in parallel: Windows and Ubuntu.

When I build APK in Windows (via command line) - the APK is fine and runs great.
But when I build exactly the same project on Ubuntu - it fails (running on the same Android device).

I clone the project from the same git repository, and during the gradle build - I receive the one-to-one same messages.

Have no idea where I should start digging.

Any advise will be appreciated.

BTW, I have run-time logs from both APK's:

The logs:

```
============  Linux  ============
08-16 09:02:35.455 5866-5975/com.growdirector.tabletapp.growdirectorapp D/JVM: JNIEnvironment::RegisterNatives(org/webrtc/voiceengine/WebRtcAudioManager)


    NativeRegistration::ctor@[tid=5975]
    NativeRegistration::NewObject@[tid=5975]

08-16 09:02:35.455 5866-5975/com.growdirector.tabletapp.growdirectorapp W/System.err: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lorg/webrtc/voiceengine/WebRtcAudioManager;.<init>(Landroid/content/Context;J)V"
08-16 09:02:35.456 5866-5975/com.growdirector.tabletapp.growdirectorapp E/rtc: #
    # Fatal error in ../../webrtc/modules/utility/source/helpers_android.cc, line 51
    # last system error: 0
    # Check failed: !jni->ExceptionCheck()
    # Error during GetMethodID: <init>, (Landroid/content/Context;J)V
    #
========================================================



========  WIN =========================================
08-14 19:06:15.210 2483-2656/com.growdirector.tabletapp.growdirectorapp D/JVM: JNIEnvironment::RegisterNatives(org/webrtc/voiceengine/WebRtcAudioManager)

    NativeRegistration::ctor@[tid=2656]
    NativeRegistration::NewObject@[tid=2656]

08-14 19:06:15.211 2483-2656/com.growdirector.tabletapp.growdirectorapp I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioManager: ctor@[name=Thread-318, id=318]



08-14 19:06:15.213 211-838/? D/AudioFlinger_Threads: thread 0xad4c0000 type 0 TID 838 waking up
08-14 19:06:15.213 211-840/? D/AudioFlinger_Threads: thread 0xad200000 type 0 TID 840 waking up
08-14 19:06:15.214 211-838/? D/AudioALSAStreamOut: latency(), flags 2, return 23
08-14 19:06:15.214 211-840/? D/AudioALSAStreamOut: latency(), flags 4, return 10
08-14 19:06:15.214 801-1380/? D/PowerManagerService: acquireWakeLockInternal: lock=137038916, flags=0x1, tag="AudioMix", ws=null, uid=1013, pid=0
    updateWakeLockSummaryLocked: mWakefulness=Awake, mWakeLockSummary=0x1
08-14 19:06:15.214 2483-2568/com.growdirector.tabletapp.growdirectorapp D/AudioSystem: getIoDescriptor: ioHandle = 2, index = -2, mIoDescriptors = 0x9db88218
```

======================================================

Thanks!

Comment: The error occurs during run-time, the installation goes smooth

Comment: that's strange, can you paste error !